# Function to retrieve value from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do you write a function that returns a value fetched from server via `$.get`?

This is what I have tried, which does not work:

```
function getMessage(key) {
    $.get("/messages.json", function(data) {
        return data.messages[key];
    }, "json");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we a snippet of the (hopefully) JSON format data returned by `messages.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Ajax requests are *asynchronous*. That is why you have to pass a callback to `$.get`, to handle the data *once it is available*. But the `getMessage` function returns before the `$.get` callback is executed.
You have to pass a callback that is doing something with the return value. E.g.:

```
function getMessage(key, cb) {
  $.get("/messages.json", function(data) {
    cb(data.messages[key]);
  }, "json");
}

getMessage('foo', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Of course you can also pass the callack directly to `$.get` and handle the data extraction there:

```
function getMessage(cb) {
  $.get("/messages.json", cb);
}
```

Comment: +1 but the last sentence is confusing. `getMessage` returns immediately anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: Yes I fixed that ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this: use a synchronmous call via `$.ajax` or pass in a callback to your function instead of having it return a value.  The latter is the canonical way to deal with AJAX since it retains the asynchronous nature of the call.

**Asynchronous**

```
function processMessage(key,elem,cb) {
     $.get('/messages.json', function(data) {
           if (cb && typeof(cb) === 'function') {
               cb.apply(elem,data.messages[key]);
           }
     }
}


$('.something').each( function() {
      processMessage('somekey', this, function(msg) {
            $(this).append(msg);
      });
});
```

**Synchronous** - try not to do it this way, since you'll lock your browser until it's done.

```
function getMessage(key)
{
   var result = '';
   $.ajax({
       url: '/messages.json',
       aSync: false,
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
                     result = data.messages[key];
                }
   });
   return result;
}

$('.something').each( function() {
    var msg = getMessage('somekey');
    $(this).append(msg);
});
```

Note: these are untested.